# Background color not working?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to hover a text in an image. If I set a background color for the text it is not working. It will work if I use `position: absolute;` but it is hovering my header too.

```css
.comimg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 75%;
}
.tren {
  margin-top: -250px;
  margin-bottom: -300px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: aqua;
  overflow: none;
}
.trust p {
  margin-top: -19;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  color: #424242;
}
.comimg p {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: aliceblue;
  background-color: aqua;
  font-weight: 900;
}
.comimg img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="comimg">
  <img src="img/6042013705_eb32ce58fa_o.jpg" />
  <div class="tren">
    <p>#trending</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the result you are trying to achieve? You want the background to stretch just for the width of the text?

Comment: I recommend you take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp property in CSS.

Comment: @Nathangrad try to avoid to link to w3schools. While they fixed many errors on the page there are still inaccuracies and misleading informations on their page. They got better compared to the years before, but it is still not a good source of information. Here they e.g. write `[...]An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order.[...]`, but they don't add an  obvious link to a page where they describe it in detail. An element with the z-index 3 can be behind one with the z-index -1  depending on the nesting structure.

Comment: @fbid Actually i am trying to achieve a Text hovering in a image

Comment: Means you want to hover the text and change the background & color of that text? or hover the image and change the background & color of text?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding you can achieve that effect using CSS and HTML.

I'm using `:hover` selector on the `.wrapper` div, in order to apply different styles based on the result I want to achieve.

**EXAMPLE**

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

main {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: url('http://lorempixel.com/500/500/abstract') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  display: table;
}

.wrapper:hover {
  background: #fda;
}

.wrapper:hover p {
  background: #345;
  display: block;
}

p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2.4em;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <p>
      #trending
    </p>
  </div>
</main>
```